# How do I change the HTML content of a dynamically generated element in Jquery

Tags: jquery, dynamically-generated

I long ago learned that for dynamically added content, attaching listeners and events like click and focus must be done by using `$(document).on('click','[ID]', function(){});`.... etc.

However, what I'm trying to do is change the HTML value of a specific element that has been dynamically added.

For instance, I use this code to add the element:

```
$('.friend_chooser_pop').html("<div id='#friend_chooser_list'></div>");
```

Now how do I access #friend_chooser_list and set its HTML value? Neither one of these works:

```
$('#friend_chooser_list').html('something');
document.getElementById('friend_chooser_list').innerHTML = 'something';
```

Comment: `html("<div id='#friend_chooser_list'></div>");` your div id shouldnt include a `#`.. that should fix your problem

Comment: Gosh darn it... Yeah. that was it.THANKS!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work, your problem is that you included a `#` in your id, this is not needed here.

This would work.

```
$('.friend_chooser_pop').html("<div id='friend_chooser_list'></div>");
$('#friend_chooser_list').html('something');
```

If this is your intend to include `#` in the ID and you want it to work you can use it like this:

```
$("#\\#friend_chooser_list").html('something');
```

It's escaping the `#` and allowing jQuery to get the right element anyway. I would not recommend this, it can get confusing pretty fast.

Comment: Someone answered this in the comments above already, but I'm marking this as the solution so anyone else who completely missed the obvious like I did can find the answer quickly.

Answer (score 3):

When you dynamically add elements to the page, you have to refresh the event listeners.

You should group all your event listeners in a function :

```
function bindEvents(){
    $('*').off();

    $('a.fonction').click(function(){
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

The first line (.off()) remove all the listener on the page (* = all the element, like in CSS).

Then just recall this function when you change the content of the page.

Have fun !

Comment: Not when you are using `$(document).on('click','[ID]', function(){});` that listener is appended to the document, not the element. The problem is with the selector he is using, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.friend_chooser_pop #friend_chooser_list').html('something');
```

You can give it parent context and change `$('.friend_chooser_pop').html("<div id='#friend_chooser_list'></div>");` to `$('.friend_chooser_pop').html("<div id='friend_chooser_list'></div>");`, in order to be visible in DOM for jQuery